# Pass value by reference to COM object function

Tags: php

I have COM object, that contains function:

```
[id(1)]  HRESULT tst1([out] LONG * l, [out, retval] LONG * e );
```

Create this object and use in PHP and pass parameter by reference:

```
$i=5;
$f = new COM('App.MyObj');
$f->tst1(&$i);
```

Got error:

```
Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated
```

If I pass `$i` without `&` (that should define "by reference") I have the same value of `i` equals to `5` after `tst1()` execution

```
$i=5;
$f = new COM('App.MyObj');
$f->tst1($i);
```

But inside of COM object function definitely changes passed value

```
STDMETHODIMP CSomeObject::tst1(LONG* e)
{
    *e=3;
    return S_OK;
}
```

How to pass by reference in `PHP` while calling `COM` object function?

Comment: Assuming `tst1` returns a value... `$i = $f->tst1($i);`

Comment: @hd COM functions only return status codes. Values are almost always out-params, so passing in a reference from PHP is a natural fit.

Comment: @vico what version of PHP? 'cause the http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php docs say "Starting with PHP 5, PHP will automatically detect methods that accept parameters by reference..."

Comment: Problem solved. My mistake - originally, in  COM function IDL was [in] instead of [out]